# Can I do an entire Time Machine restore to another computer?

Tags: macos, time-machine, restore

I made a Time Machine backup of my 2015 MacBook Air to a USB drive.  I want to restore the entire state of the OS and my files to a 2015 MacBook Pro.

On the MacBook Pro I booted into Internet Recovery and used Disk Utility to erase/partition the internal drive.

Then I quit Disk Utility and ran "Restore from Time Machine".  I selected my backup from my external drive and proceeded with the restore.  It took about an hour and finished without any error messages.

But then when I shutdown, disconnected by backup drive and restarted the only boot option I had was Internet Recovery.  I rebooted while holding option key and still only Internet Recovery was the only option.  Is there something else I need to do?

The Time Machine backup is of a 10.14.6 system.
On the target MacBook Pro the disk is configured as:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                   Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           250.7 GB   disk0s2
```

Comment: As of 10.14 HFS+ volumes are not supported as boot volumes. You have to install Mojave via Mojave Installer thumb drive and transfer the data from the backup drive in the configuration screen (3rd or 4th step? - I don't rememebr). Under certain circumstances it may be possible to reinstall the current macOS but I don't know whether this works if the main drive is no valid boot drive.

Comment: I think the issue was the HFS+ volume.  When I booted from internet recovery I think it used the Sierra recovery because disk utility had no APFS option.  I installed Mojave and then booted to the local recovery and I was able to create the APFS volume.  Then after restoring my Time Machine backup it was able to boot.

Comment: That's what I tried to explain with my comment: *"As of 10.14 HFS+ volumes are not supported as boot volumes"*. If you **install** Mojave (instead of copying it) the destination (HFS+) volume will be converted to APFS automatically...

Comment: Thanks for your help @klanomath.  I wouldn't have been able to figure that one out on my own.   In case anyone else does this I also found that I needed to delete the ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost directory in order to be able to login after the time machine restore to the new computer.

Comment: I will try to write a more or less comprehensive answer how to restore an APFS volume with Time Machine to another machine after testing it in a virtual machine. ;-)